# reshape pandas column to allow sum instead of all values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data frame with 10 columns which successfully loads into a classifier. Now I am trying to load the sum of the columns instead of all 10 columns.

```
previous_games_stats = pd.read_csv('stats/2016-2017 CANUCKS STATS.csv', header=1)
numGamesToLookBack = 10;

X = previous_games_stats[['GF', 'GA']]

X = X[0:numGamesToLookBack] #num games to look back
stats_feature_names = list(X.columns.values)

totals = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names)

y = previous_games_stats['Unnamed: 7'] #outcome variable (win/loss)
y = y[numGamesToLookBack+1]

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names).sum()
```

The final line (with `.sum()` at the end) causes `stats_df` to go form being formatted like:

```
   GF  GA
0   2   1
1   4   3
2   2   1
3   2   1
4   3   4
5   2   4
6   0   3
7   0   2
8   2   5
9   0   3
```

to:

```
GF    17
GA    27
```

But I want to keep the same format, so the end result should be this:

```
    GF    GA
0   17    27
```

Since it is getting re-formatted, I am getting the following error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3
```

**What can I do to make the format stay the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If call `sum` to `DataFrame`, get `Series`. For one row `DataFrame` use:

```
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names).sum().to_frame().T
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names)
stats_df = pd.DataFrame([df1.sum().values], columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Can you help me with something else please? I have a similar problem with pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463949/appending-dataframe-to-empty-dataframe-is-not-working