# Appending dataframe to empty dataframe is not working

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I declared an empty data frame near the top of my file with a global scope:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

I have `stats_df`successfully printing the correct value, but `final_df` is not changing after appending stats_df to it:

```
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names).sum().to_frame().T
print('statsdf being appended: \n', stats_df)
print('final_df before append: \n', final_df)
final_df.append(stats_df)
print('final_df after append: \n', final_df)
```

The output of these print statements are:

```
statsdf being appended: 
    GF  GA
0  14  33
final_df before append: 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
final_df after append: 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

When it **should** be:

```
statsdf being appended: 
    GF  GA
0  14  33
final_df before append: 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
final_df after append: 
 GF  GA
0  14  33
```

**Why is `stats_df` not being appended to `final_df`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need assign to new `DataFrame`, because use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), not pure python `append`:

```
stats_feature_names = ['a','b']
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

X = [[1,2]]
stats_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=stats_feature_names).sum().to_frame().T
print('statsdf being appended: \n', stats_df)
print('final_df before append: \n', final_df)
final_df = final_df.append(stats_df, ignore_index=True)
print('final_df after append: \n', final_df)
    a  b
0  1  2
```

But better solution is append to list (pure python append) and out of loop use `concat`:

```
L = []
for x in iterator:
    stats_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=stats_feature_names).sum().to_frame().T
    L.append(stats_df)

final_df = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True)
print('final_df after append: \n', final_df)
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Only problem is that when I use this, the index in the data frame is not incrementing:

`final_df after append: 
    GF  GA
0  17  27
0  15  27
0  14  30
0  14  33`

Comment: You need `, ignore_index=True)`, check edited answer.